# How to make STS or Maven stop generating JAR in project directory?

Tags: java, maven, jar, spring-tool-suite

I have this code in pom.xml regarding `<build></build>`

```
<build>
    <finalName>Fleaty</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Every time I go Run As -> Spring Boot application, I get some jar file in project directory. How to not make STS or Maven generate jar file?

I cannot gitignore it.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your launch config has probably the option checked to generate a temporary JAR to avoid classpath length issues - in the launch config on the `Classpath` tab.

Depending on the number of JAR files on your classpath, the command to launch your app might get very very long and might cause trouble with some limitations on Windows for the length of the command line (that is being executed to run your app). To workaround this limitation, the IDE generates a temporary JAR and runs the app from there. But you can disable that in the launch config.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your reply. Yeah, I found where to uncheck the option you are referring to , I think. So I did: right click on the project -> Run As -> Run Configuration -> Classpath tab -> uncheck: "Use temporary JAR to specify classpath (to avoid classpath length limitations). After that, when I started app with Spring Boot Run App, there is message in the console: Couldn't find the main class,

Comment: In my experience, there are multiple reasons possible for that message. I would try a "Project -> Clean" and a "Maven -> Update Project". Sometimes the classpath containers get messed up and those actions help to fix that. But maybe you are indeed hitting this classpath limitation issue on Windows, in which case I would recommend to raise a bug at Eclipse JDT and ask for advice. You could also try to create a sample project that reproduces the issue, so that we can take a closer look.